# Dynamixel 2.0 - Execute Joint Trajectories

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have been using `dynamixel_motor` package which provides `joint_trajectory_action_controller.py` to send `trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory` to my manipulator. Is there something similar in DynamixelSDK or dynamixel_workbench? From what I can tell from their [tutorials](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/software/dynamixel/dynamixel_workbench/#tutorials), it is only possible to send a single joint command (to either a single motor, or multiple connected motors).

Update (6/4/18):

dynamixel_motor package does this through `set_multi_position_and_speed(self, valueTuples)` by calling `self.sync_write(DXL_GOAL_POSITION_L, tuple(writeableVals))` with `writeableVals = (sid, loPositionVal, hiPositionVal, loSpeedVal, hiSpeedVal)`. Would something like this work in `dynamixel_workbench` by setting position and speed using `Goal_Position` for ControlTableItem? If so, how would I call it using `writeRegister()`?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292986/dynamixel-2.0---execute-joint-trajectories/) by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 592 on 2018-06-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on 2018-06-03**:
Sorry, that example is not supported in DynamixelSDK and Dynamixel Workbench. But you can get other example how to control manipulator using it in [OpenManipulator](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/open_manipulator)

**Comment by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on 2018-06-06**:
You can refer this link http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/software/dynamixel/dynamixel_workbench/#library

**Comment by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on 2018-06-07**:
Do you know if it would work to send a goalPosition and goalSpeed at the same time, would they both be accepted or just one? If so, I might be able to use bulkWrite().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to figure it out for `trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory` by using the following:

```
  ROS_INFO("Joint trajectory consists of %ld points.", jointTrajectory.points.size());
  ros::Time trajectoryStartTime = ros::Time::now();
  for (int i = 0; i < jointTrajectory.points.size(); i++)
  {
    while ( (ros::Time::now() - trajectoryStartTime).toSec() < jointTrajectory.points[i].time_from_start.toSec() )
    {
      continue;
    }
    int32_t speed = dxl_wb_->convertVelocity2Value(dxl_id_[index], jointTrajectory.points[i].velocities[0]);
    int32_t position = dxl_wb_->convertRadian2Value(dxl_id_[index], jointTrajectory.points[i].positions[0]);
    dxl_wb_->itemWrite(dxl_id_[index], "Profile_Velocity", speed);
    dxl_wb_->goalPosition(dxl_id_[index], position);
    ROS_INFO("Writing position to Dynamixel motor #%d: [%d, %d] at time %f.", dxl_id_[index], position, speed, (ros::Time::now() - trajectoryStartTime).toSec());
  }
```

---

Originally posted by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) with karma: 592 on 2018-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0